# Changing height of an UIImageView by behavior

Tags: uiimageview, size

I have a Custom tableviewcell which is loaded to the TableView that loads images of different sizes from an array in to a UIImageView (in the tableviewcell), At this point the images scales to fit in the Imageview that have CGRect CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 300);

But what i want it to do is keep the setting of Width 280, and change the height of the UIImageView so that the image still have the right proportions

Been looking around alot and havnt found an answer.
How do i go about doing this?

Grateful for any help